# Hyperledger Fabric v1.1.0 byfn tutorial on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

```
root@sungil:~/fabric-samples/first-network# export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel
root@sungil:~/fabric-samples/first-network# ../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
2018-03-19 13:11:51.489 KST [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2018-03-19 13:11:51.494 KST [common/tools/configtxgen] doOutputChannelCreateTx -> INFO 002 Generating new channel configtx
2018-03-19 13:11:51.495 KST [msp] getMspConfig -> INFO 003 Loading NodeOUs
2018-03-19 13:11:51.495 KST [msp] getMspConfig -> INFO 004 Loading NodeOUs
2018-03-19 13:11:51.510 KST [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> CRIT 005 Error on outputChannelCreateTx: config update generation failure: could not parse application to application group: setting up the MSP manager failed: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.org2.example.com")
```

I installed hyperledger fabric v1.1.0-rc1 using byfn.sh.

(Reference:
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/lastest/build_network.html)

But I got some failure. It's Fabric CA problem?

**[executed]**

```
./byfn.sh -m generate

./byfn.sh -m up

../bin/cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml

export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD

../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block

export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel

./bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
```

my configtx.yaml is https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.1/first-network/configtx.yaml

Comment: you need to add content of your configtx.yaml file, since looks like the problem is there.

Comment: @ArtemBarger I’m using the sample configtx.yaml file. No edit configtx.yaml. Please explain how to edit this stiuation...

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue. What helped me was to start over.

- Bring down the network: `./byfn.sh -m down`
- Clean up the generated artifacts

  - `rm crypto-config`
  - `rm channel-artifacts`

Then issue again the commands. This helped me, the channel.tx and other were successfully created. No need to change the configtx.yaml from the sample.

Comment: Thank you. And sorry.. I just didn't "./byfn.sh -m down". But your Answer was helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to delete files you just need to make sure that ./byfn.sh -m down was executed prior to steps in Crypto Generator section