# hyperledger : error creating a Channel Configuration Transaction

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have been following this link : http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#troubleshoot for starting my first network, using byfn.sh file, and have executed all steps till

```
export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel  && ../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
himani@himani-HP-Notebook:~/fabric-samples/first-network$ export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannelthis  && ../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME2018-06-07 11:42:00.552 IST [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2018-06-07 11:42:00.560 IST [common/tools/configtxgen] doOutputChannelCreateTx -> INFO 002 Generating new channel configtx
2018-06-07 11:42:00.560 IST [msp] getMspConfig -> INFO 003 Loading NodeOUs
2018-06-07 11:42:00.561 IST [msp] getMspConfig -> INFO 004 Loading NodeOUs
2018-06-07 11:42:00.579 IST [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> CRIT 005 Error on outputChannelCreateTx: config update generation failure: could not parse application to application group: setting up the MSP manager failed: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.org1.example.com")
```

I have tried variations of the command,

```
export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannelanother  && ../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME

export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannelanother  && ../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $mychannelanother

export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel  && ../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $mychannel
```

I even tried creating a channel without using byfn.sh file, but got a different error

```
himani@himani-HP-Notebook:~/fabric-samples/first-network$ peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
No command 'peer' found, did you mean:
 Command 'pear' from package 'php-pear' (main)
 Command 'pee' from package 'moreutils' (universe)
 Command 'peet' from package 'pipexec' (universe)
 Command 'beer' from package 'gerstensaft' (universe)
peer: command not found
himani@himani-HP-Notebook:~/fabric-samples/first-network$ peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannelthis -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
No command 'peer' found, did you mean:
 Command 'pear' from package 'php-pear' (main)
 Command 'pee' from package 'moreutils' (universe)
 Command 'beer' from package 'gerstensaft' (universe)
 Command 'peet' from package 'pipexec' (universe)
peer: command not found
```

I modified the */home/himani/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/tlsca/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem* doc by referring to this link : https://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/#/c/18177/ , and executed the command again, but to no avail.

Are my certificates outdated? Where can I find the right ones? Is the issue something else?

**UPDATE:**
After referring to a solution provided to a similar problem, [Hyperledger Fabric v1.1.0 byfn tutorial on Ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356066/hyperledger-fabric-v1-1-0-byfn-tutorial-on-ubuntu-16-04?rq=1), I brought down my network and tried to clean up artifacts but I couldn't execute those commands. Channel artifacts folder is empty.

[I couldn't execute those commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOwl4.png)

Answer (score 0):

This command is meant to add files in channel-artifacts folder, but for some reason the folder was not created automatically. On creating one, with adequate permissions, the command executed and genesis block was created.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have solved it or not, but there are some mistakes there.

```
himani@himani-HP-Notebook:~/fabric-samples/first-network$ export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannelthis  && ../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME2018-06-07 11:42:00.552 IST [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2018-06-07 11:42:00.560 IST [common/tools/configtxgen] doOutputChannelCreateTx -> INFO 002 Generating new channel configtx
2018-06-07 11:42:00.560 IST [msp] getMspConfig -> INFO 003 Loading NodeOUs
2018-06-07 11:42:00.561 IST [msp] getMspConfig -> INFO 004 Loading NodeOUs
2018-06-07 11:42:00.579 IST [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> CRIT 005 Error on outputChannelCreateTx: config update generation failure: could not parse application to application group: setting up the MSP manager failed: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.org1.example.com")
```

if you are following the tutorial, CHANNEL_NAME should be `mychannel`.

for the 3rd variations, it should be like this

```
export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel  && ../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
```

for creating channel, peer channel create can only be send inside docker container.
If you are sending directly from command line, try this

```
docker exec -it yourCliContainerName peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannelthis -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

but remember to start the container first.

hope this helps